# Gradle Coverage with Cobertura and Sonar

Tags: android, gradle, sonarqube, cobertura, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to configure our Android Gradle build to publish code coverage results (generated by Cobertura) to Sonar.

We have a modular project structure where each module is built as an apk-lib or apk.  The project is structured like so:

```
build.gradle (top-level gradle build script)
settings.gradle (top-level gradle settings)
android_lib.gradle (used by module's build.gradle to tell it to build module as apk-lib)
android_app.gradle (as above but apk)
|
|__module1
|____build.gradle
|
|
|__module2
|____build.gradle
|
|
|__module3
|____build.gradle
|
|__etc...
```

I have had some luck generating the coverage using Cobertura.  I can see the html and xml coverage reports in `build/reports/cobertura/coverage.xml`.  This is how I've configured it:

`android_lib.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'net.saliman.cobertura'

cobertura {
    coverageFormats = ['html', 'xml']               
    coverageIgnoreTrivial = true                    
    coverageIgnores = ['org.slf4j.Logger.*']            
    coverageReportDir = new File("$buildDir/reports/cobertura") 
}

android {
    ...   //android specific config goes here
}
```

After I run `gradlew cobertura` the coverage reports are generated and exist in `build/reports/cobertura/coverage.xml`

Now I would like to be able to publish these results to a local Sonar (v4.3) server I have running.

I have tried applying the sonar-runner plugin to my `android_lib.gradle` file but I receive lots and lots of errors and do not see any coverage results in Sonar.

`android_lib.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'sonar-runner'

sonarRunner {
   sonarProperties {
    //property "sonar.projectKey", "coverage-example"
    //property "sonar.projectName", "Coverage Example"
    //property "sonar.projectVersion", "1.0"

    property "sonar.sources", "src/main/java"
    property "sonar.binaries", "build"
    //property "sonar.test", "src/androidTest/java"

    property "sonar.profile", "Sonar way"
    property "sonar.language", "java"
    property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"

    property "sonar.dynamicAnalysis", "reuseReports"

    property "sonar.junit.reportsPath", "build/test-results/debug"
    property "sonar.cobertura.reportPath", "build/reports/cobertura/coverage.xml"
    property "sonar.java.coveragePlugin", "cobertura"

    property "sonar.host.url", "http://localhost:9000"
    }
}
```

Is there something I am missing, has anyone had luck with this setup?